# Windows 10 Update: Borland.Delphi.Targets disappeared

Tags: .net, delphi, windows-10, delphi-2007

I've turned on my PC 1 hour ago and it told me: "Hello .... you Windows has been updated with new features .." and so on.
That's ok.

Then I compiled an app on Delphi XE3: that's ok too.

Then another one in Delphi 2007, and the following message appeared:

> Unable to load project xxxxx The imported project
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Delphi.Targets"
>   was not found.

I just had this problem weeks ago and solved with this answer on Stackoverflow: [Delphi 2007 x Windows 10 - Error on opening project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745712/delphi-2007-x-windows-10-error-on-opening-project)

But it seems this automatic Windows upgade had now deleted my files: I do not find it in any c:\Windows subfolder.

Comment: Do you have a `Windows.old` directory in the root of your system drive?

Comment: I found them in C:\ProgramData. Did you search your drive for files starting with `Borland.` to see where they're located? Explorer finds them easily.

Comment: Known problem with Delphi 2007 on Vista onward: http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2013/11/10/delphi-2007-on-windows-8-1/

Comment: I've solved with a files restore (I had a valid backup...), but Ok Lasse: I'found the Borland.Common.Targets, Borland.Cpp.Targets, Borland.Delphi.Targets and Borland.Group.Targets in "C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"

Comment: Ok Ken: I've found them in "C:\ProgramData\{B59CE2E6-B15A-4F23-BD0E-72BF2ADDC3C7}\core\7EFD2DA3\6C948720" folder too. I've solved with an external restore, but thanks to anyone. In legacy Dephi 2007 projects on Windows 10 is a must to have a copy of these files: it seems they are deleted/moved on automatic windows updates.

Comment: You don't need an external restore. You can copy them directly into the folder described in the linked post. There's no other work involved. Shift-click the four files, right-click and choose Copy, and then paste them into the proper framework folder.

Comment: Also, when you're addressing a comment to someone else, precede their name with `@`, as in `@joesmith`, and they'll get a notification in their inbox to let them know you've done so. It only works when replying to a comment or question, and only to the person who posted the comment or question; you can't use it to ping other people here.