# Delphi 2007 on Windows 10 - Download Borland.xxx.Targets files

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

as described in 
[Delphi 2007 x Windows 10 - Error on opening project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745712/delphi-2007-x-windows-10-error-on-opening-project)
I am looking for the following files as deleted by Windows update

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Common.Targets
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Cpp.Targets
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Delphi.Targets
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Group.Targets
```

The Windows.old folder is long gone, and I can't find those files in the ProgramData folder.
Can anyone upload and share them?

Thank you,
Fabio

Comment: Restore your delphi installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my reference system, these files are also in this directory:

```
C:\ProgramData\{B59CE2E6-B15A-4F23-BD0E-72BF2ADDC3C7}\core\7EFD2DA3\6C948720
```

Others seem to have them [there as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745712/delphi-2007-x-windows-10-error-on-opening-project#comment52981589_31745908).

And they are at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab801cd925e5e634518fd5592eb2a46e